# How to create a script that scans web server while parsing IP's into list (py3)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

For my intro class I have to create a script that scans for a web server. The scanning should be implemented in a module and the user input and output should be implemented in a script that imports the module.

So far for my actual script (not module I have this)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re
import socket

hostServer = input("Enter an IP address or list (seperated by commas) to scan: ").split(',')

import socketmodule

print("-" * 60)
print("Please wait, scanning remote host", remoteServer)
print("-" * 60)
```

I have this for my module at the moment

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket

s=socket.socket()
s.connect((hostServer, 80))  # I'm getting an error for using hostServer but 
                               how else should I pass the list of IP 
                               addresses into my module?
s.send(b'GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n')
s.recv(1024)
while True:
    data.s.recv(1024)
    if data:
       print('Recieved {} bytes from client at {}.\n{}'.format(len(data), addr, data))
       conn.sendall(data)
       break
s.close()
```

Can someone please direct me out of this mess

Answer (score 0):

#### How to listen to multiple ports

You need to create one socket per one port, this means you can't use plain methods call just by importing a module.

#### Extract your code into a function or into a class. Here is an example:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3

import socket

class PortListener(object):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 1024

    def __init__(self, host_server, port):
        self.host = host_server
        self.port = port

    def listen(self):
        self.socket = socket.socket()
        self.socket.connect((self.host, self.port))
        self.socket.send(b'GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n')
        while True:
            data = self.socket.recv(self.CHUNK_SIZE)
            if data:
                print('Recieved {} bytes from client at {}.\n{}'.format(len(data), '{}:{}'.format(self.host,
                    self.port), data))

    def close(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.socket.close()
```

Then you create an instance of listener per port

```
from socketmodule import PortListener
listener = PortListener('127.0.0.1', 5000)
```

#### Possible issues:

For reserved ports (any port under 1024) you need a root access to listen to it.

You may need to think about a loop to create a pool of listeners to receive data from multiple ports. Please also make sure that socket is closed once you finished interacting with a web server.